# Rails 2.3 "inline_attachment" gem incorrect placement of inline attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, attachment

I'm at the point where the entire email and it's parts generate in the correct order and nesting...except for one little thing.  The :part_container parameter inserts the inline attachments ABOVE the text/html part instead of BELOW it.  If it's above, Thunderbird won't display anything and it'll show the email as having 2 external attachments.  If I manually edit the email and move the inline parts below the text/html part, it shows perfectly.

```
part :content_type => 'multipart/alternative' do |copy|
    copy.part :content_type => 'text/plain' do |plain|
        plain.body = render(
            :file => "main.text.plain", 
            :body => {
                    :user => @user,
                    :text => docParse.to_plain_text
                    }
            )
    end
    copy.part :content_type => 'multipart/related' do |rel|
        rel.part :content_type => 'text/html' do |html|
            html.body = render(
                :file => "main.text.html",
                :body => {
                        :part_container => rel,
                        :user => @user,
                        :content => content,
                        :email_links => m.email_links,
                        :nav_image => m.nav_image
                        }
                )
        end
    end
end
m.attachments.each do |file|
    attachment :content_type => "application/octet-stream",
               :filename     => File.basename(file),
               :body         => File.read(file)
end
```

To be clear, the inline_attachments gem works perfectly without any of this code - but that's only when I'm sending an email without any external attachments (only inline images).  When I want to send an HTML email with inline images AND external attachments, this is what I have to resort to.

EDIT: To be clear, my question is "how do I make sure that the inline attachment parts are generated AFTER the text/html part using :part_container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts contain a parts array...

```
rel.parts.unshift rel.parts.pop
```

Essentially an email is comprised of 'parts'...these parts belong to an array of parts and each part can have their own array of parts (nested parts).  Seeing as how the :part_container argument from the 'inline_attachments' gem created parts in the wrong order (text/html part LAST instead of FIRST), I reordered the relative parts array by popping the last part item - which happened to be the text/html part (rel.parts.pop) and inserting it as the 1st item in the relative parts array (rel.parts.unshift)

i.e.,
inline-image-part
inline-image-part
inline-image-part
text/html-part

became

text/html-part
inline-image-part
inline-image-part
inline-image-part

And everything displayed properly.

This is the latest script with reference to the script in my problem:

```
part :content_type => 'multipart/alternative' do |copy|
    copy.part :content_type => 'text/plain' do |plain|
        plain.body = render(
            :file => "main.text.plain", 
            :body => {
                    :user => @user,
                    :text => docParse.to_plain_text
                    }
            )
    end
    copy.part :content_type => 'multipart/related' do |rel|
        rel.part :content_type => 'text/html' do |html|
            html.body = render(
                :file => "main.text.html",
                :body => {
                        :part_container => rel,
                        :user => @user,
                        :content => content,
                        :email_links => m.email_links,
                        :nav_image => m.nav_image
                        }
                )
        end
        # Place the text/html part before all other inline images
        rel.parts.unshift rel.parts.pop
    end
end
m.attachments.each do |file|
    attachment :content_type => "application/octet-stream",
               :filename     => File.basename(file),
               :body         => File.read(file)
end
```

Comment: Is this an answer, a comment, or ..?

Comment: It's listed as an answer.  I was going to mark it as answered but I had to wait 2 days.

Comment: I'm just asking because to me it is not clear how this answers your question. Of course, for you it is clear, but even when you answer your questions yourself, do it in a way that others can benefit from your findings, i.e. be more verbose :)