# Rails ActionMailer get content type separator string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, attachment, actionmailer

Working off of [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719016/rails-2-3-inline-attachment-gem-incorrect-placement-of-inline-attachments), I've decided that if the html.body is generated (part separators included), I could just make an array from the string, split by the part separator and reorder it myself.  How do I get the part separator string from the following block?

```
copy.part :content_type => 'multipart/related' do |rel|
rel.part :content_type => 'text/html' do |html|
    html.body = render(
        :file => "main.text.html",
        :body => {
                :part_container => rel,
                :user => @user,
                :content => content,
                :email_links => m.email_links,
                :nav_image => m.nav_image
                }
        )
    end
    # I assume 'rel' is a 'part'...but how do I get "--93920293920-relative" for example from the html.body string?
    html.body.split(???)
end
```

EDIT: Forget it, mission accomplished.  A simple array fiddling fixed it:

```
rel.parts.unshift rel.parts.pop
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? We need an example of what it is you're trying to do/formulate your question better

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had linked to my other question but I guess I forgot. Essentially the inline attachment parts which the "inline_attachment" gem creates are generated BEFORE the text/html part and thus some email clients won't display the email properly.  The inline attachment parts should come AFTER the text/html part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as how each part can have an array of parts...

rel.parts.unshift rel.parts.pop